# Choropleth Alternative Method and more

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

In my previous [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42807618/map-legend-on-same-svg) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42700208/d3js-circles-on-a-map-projection-issue), i managed to fix the choropleth map/legend issue + draw circles problems when drawing a map.

When i follow this [must-do tutorial](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606) about choropleth and when i search on internet i always find the same logic

> d3.csv("my.csv", function(data) {
>
> d3.json(myjson, function(json) {
>
> for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
>
> ```
>                   //Grab state name
>                   var dataState = data[i].nom;
>
>                   //Grab data value, and convert from string to float
>                   var dataValue = data[i].population;
>
>                   //Find the corresponding state inside the GeoJSON
>                   for (var j = 0; j < json.features.length; j++) {
>
>                       var jsonState = json.features[j].properties.nom;
>
>                       if (dataState == jsonState) {
>
>                           //Copy the data value into the JSON
>                           json.features[j].properties.CA = dataValue;
>
>                           //Stop looking through the JSON
>                           break;
>                       }
>                   }       
>               }
> ```

So in my case, i have a map with 75 path (1 path=region) and my csv file have 75 rows (1 row = 1 path)

Now i'm trying to do things a little differently

My new csv has N rows (N > 75, let's say 200) and for each row, a store (properties+lat+lon) is affected to a path ==> i can have 5 stores/path e.g

Here are my questions :

1) How do i write my choropleth code differently ==> I'd like to scan the csv file and return for each distinct path the sum of specific properties  (here "income") in order to write it on my json file ???

2) When i click on a specific region/path, i'd like to display on a new div (in my case #output) the json file corresponding to my region (basicaly i have 75 json files "region1.json", "region2.json" and so on...") with circles inside (one circle =  one store, in my csv file "name" column") ==> How do i retrieve this "on click value" and call the correct/corresponding json file ????

3) Finally, if i click on a displayed specific circle of the #output div, i'd like to have on a third div a chart ==> How do i writte correctly my 3rd div so it is correctly displayed (css, other ?? ==> it can be applied to #output too) ??

Thank you so much for reading this request and for your availability and help

Here's the [plunker file](http://plnkr.co/edit/62v7rBFSTGrbqpDohZU7?p=preview) (do not mind the sales.csv file, i just used it to try displaying something when i click on the path

Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

d3 nest roll up is the solution

```
d3.csv("source-data.csv", function(error, csv_data) {
 var data = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.date;})
  .rollup(function(d) { 
   return d3.sum(d, function(g) {return g.value; });
  }).entries(csv_data);
});
```

More info [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Arrays.md#nest)